# Как ускорить алгоритм "состоит ли эта строка из повторяющихся частей"

Tags: c, оптимизация

Мне нужно что бы алгоритм определял в строке состоит ли эта строка из повторяющихся частей. Пишу на чистом C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef unsigned char bool;
static const bool False = 0;
static const bool True = 1;
#endif

bool repeatedSubstringPattern(char* s);

int main(){
    
    printf(repeatedSubstringPattern("anaanaanaana") == True ? "True\n" : "False\n");
}

int getSize (char * s) {
    char * t;
    int size = 0;

    for (t = s; *t != '\0'; t++) {
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}

int isRepeat(char* s, char* rep){
    int j = 0;
    int repSize = getSize(rep);
    int countRep = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getSize(s); i++){
        if(s[i] == rep[j]) {
            j++;
            if(repSize == j)
            { 
                j = 0; 
                countRep++;
            }
            continue;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    if(j != 0) return 0;
    return countRep;
}

bool repeatedSubstringPattern(char* s) {
    char dub[10024] = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < getSize(s); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            dub[j] = s[j];
            
        }
        if(isRepeat(s, dub) > 1) return True;
        memset(dub, 0, 255);
    }
    return False;   
}
```

Как работает этот алгоритм:

> Мы через цикл добовляем по одному символу из строки в выделеный массив char. Затем мы посимвольно начинаем сравнивать наш кусочек повторяющегося элемента с текстом. Если один из символов не совподает значит он не повторяется

Данный код работает верно:

```
Input: "anaanaanaana" Result: True 

Input: "aaaa" Result: True 

Input: "ananav" Result: False
```

Но для полной проверки программа должна пройти еще это значение(На середине он повторяется):

```
"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"
```

В этом случае программа сработает но на ее выполнение уйдет 2 минуты. Как можно переделать этот алгоритм что бы он работал быстрее.

Comment: Попробуйте длину строки раскладывать на множители и смотреть, не одинаковые ли части получаются. Например, длина 51 — проверяем, не одинаковы ли три части по 17 символов, и 17 частей по 3 символа. Больше ничего проверять не надо.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < getSize(s); i++)
Старайтесь в цикле не использовать функции (по возможности). Ибо ваш цикл, каждую итерацию вызывает подсчет длинны :) Лучше добавить переменную, присвоить ей 1 раз длину и в цикле использовать её.
int size = getSize(s);
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)

Comment: Z-функция на С++: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1200318/291659

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается я не подумал о том, что хоть в C нет ООП из за этого тип string отсутствует, но функции `strlen`, `strcat`, `strcmp` и други в могут работать с массивами char. Так что этот код можно переписать на эти функции которые гораздо оптимизирование чем то что я сверху написал.

Comment: Особое внимание уделите функции [strstr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html)